# select 1 random keyword per line in txt

Tags: php

```
$kw=explode("\n",file_get_contents("keyword.txt"));
shuffle($kw);
```

keyword.txt is just keyword in line, example :

```
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
keyword4
keyword5
keyword6
keyword7
keyword8
keyword9
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of keyword.txt - does it contain one word per line?

Comment: keyword.txt is just keyword in line, I added the example in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select a random keyword from that file:

```
<?php
//$keywords = file('keyword.txt'); OR
$keywords = explode("\n", file_get_contents('keyword.txt'));
echo $keywords[ array_rand($keywords) ];
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to explode the read string. Also, `array_rand` second parameter is optional and defaults to `1`.

Comment: Sorry. That explains why I don't use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php often.

Comment: Incidentally, I forgot that file() leaves the newline attached, so file_get_contents and then explode would probably work better.

Comment: Just add `trim` to the `$keywords[ array_rand($keywords) ]`.

Comment: +1 After the removed comments and modified question by the OP, this is probably it...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but if you want to replace your current keyword selection with a random keyword per line, you need to change:

```
$kwd=$kw[$i];
```

with something like:

```
$kwds = explode(" ", $kw[$i]);    // although I would use foreach to loop through the lines array...
$kwd = reset(shuffle($kwds));    // shuffle the keywords in that line and pick the first one
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused, are there multiple keywords on one line or just one per line?

Comment: everytime execute, it taking randomly just one keyword per line

Comment: @alyasabrina It `taking randomly just one keyword per line` seems to imply that there are multiple keywords per line...

Comment: Im sorry @jeroen, my sense in English is bad, I'll try to explain as I can. In 1 file txt, it contains 100 keyword in line, when the script execute it must pick one random keyword. When the script execute again, it must pick one random keyword again. :)

Comment: got error, Warning: reset() [function.reset]: Passed variable is not an array or object